# How to format the summary row for total in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have add the summaryType attribute ot the jQuery column I need to get the sum to be automatically calculated as see blow

```
    var localdata = [
{ "CatId" :"3", "InventoryDate":"24/11/2015 15:08:00", "CategoryName":"MECHES", "ProductCode":"50F207229#434299004", "ProductName":"MECHE LENTE", "TotalQuantity":" 8", "TotalWeight":"0,0000", "UnitMeasureCode":"Pcs", "UsedQuantity":"4", "UsedWeight ":"0,0000", "Weight":"0,00", "RemainingQuantity":"0", "RemainingWeight":"0,0000" }, { "CatId":"1", "InventoryDate":"24/11/2015 12:12:00", "CategoryName":"EXPLOSIFS", "ProductCode":"50F300440#151026E3170400596", "ProductName": "EURONIX", "TotalQuantity":"16", "TotalWeight":"25,0000", "UnitMeasureCode":"Kg" , "UsedQuantity":"0", "UsedWeight":"0,0000", "Weight":"25,00", "RemainingQuantity":"16", "RemainingWeight":"25,0000" }, { "CatId":"1", "InventoryDate":"24/11/2015 11:09:00", "CategoryName":"EXPLOSIFS", "ProductCode":"50F300440#151026E3170500598", "ProductName":"EURONIX", "TotalQuantity":"16", "TotalWeight":"25,0000", "UnitMeasureCode":"Kg" , "UsedQuantity":"0", "UsedWeight":"0,0000", "Weight":"25,00", "RemainingQuantity":"16", "RemainingWeight":"25,0000" }, { "CatId":"1", "InventoryDate":"24/11/2015 11:09:00", "CategoryName":"EXPLOSIFS", "ProductCode":"50F300440#151026E3170500599", "ProductName":"EURONIX", "TotalQuantity":"16", "TotalWeight":"25,0000", "UnitMeasureCode":"Kg ", "UsedQuantity":"0", "UsedWeight":"0,0000", "Weight":"25,00", "RemainingQuantity":"16", "RemainingWeight":"25,0000" }, { "CatId":"1", "InventoryDate":"24/11/2015 11:09:00", "CategoryName":"EXPLOSIFS", "ProductCode":"50F300440#151026E3170500600", "ProductName":"EURONIX", "TotalQuantity":"16", "TotalWeight":"25,0000", "UnitMeasureCode":"Kg" , "UsedQuantity":"5", "UsedWeight":"7,8125", "Weight":"25,00", "RemainingQuantity":"6", "RemainingWeight":"17,1875" }, { "CatId":"1", "InventoryDate":"24/11/2015 11:09:00", "CategoryName":"EXPLOSIFS", "ProductCode":"50F300440#151026E3170600601", "ProductName:":"EURONIX", "TotalQuantity":"16", "TotalWeight":"25,0000", "UnitMeasureCode":"Kg" , "UsedQuantity":"0", "UsedWeight":"0,0000","Weight":"25,00", "RemainingQuantity":"16", "RemainingWeight":"25,0000" }, { "CatId":"1", "InventoryDate":"24/11/2015 11:09:00", "CategoryName":"EXPLOSIFS", "ProductCode":"50F300440#151026E3170600602", "ProductName":"EURONIX", "TotalQuantity":"16", "TotalWeight":"25,0000", "UnitMeasureCode":"Kg" , "UsedQuantity":"0", "UsedWeight":"0,0000", "Weight":"25,00", "RemainingQuantity":"16", "RemainingWeight":"25,0000"}, { "CatId":"1", "InventoryDate":"24/11/2015 11:09:00", "CategoryName":"EXPLOSIFS", "ProductCode":"50F300440#151026E3170700603", "ProductName":"EURONIX", "TotalQuantity":"16", "TotalWeight":"25,0000", "UnitMeasureCode":"Kg" , "UsedQuantity":"0", "UsedWeight":"0,0000", "Weight":"25,00", "RemainingQuantity":" 16", "RemainingWeight":"25,0000" }, { "CatId":"1", "InventoryDate":"24/11/2015 11:09:00", "CategoryName":"EXPLOSIFS", "ProductCode":"50F300440#151026E3170700604", "ProductName":"EURONIX", "TotalQuantity":"16", "TotalWeight":"25,0000", "UnitMeasureCode":"Kg" , "UsedQuantity":"0", "UsedWeight":"0,0000","Weight":"25,00", "RemainingQuantity":"16", "RemainingWeight":"25,0000" }, { "CatId":"1", "InventoryDate":"24/11/2015 11:09:00", "CategoryName":"EXPLOSIFS", "ProductCode":"50F300440#151026E3170700605", "ProductName":"EURONIX", "TotalQuantity":"16", "TotalWeight":"25,0000", "UnitMeasureCode":"Kg" , "UsedQuantity":"0", "UsedWeight":"0,0000", "Weight":"25,00", "RemainingQuantity":" 16", "RemainingWeight":"25,0000" }, { "CatId":"1", "InventoryDate":"24/11/2015 11:09:00", "CategoryName":"EXPLOSIFS", "ProductCode":"50F300440#151026E3170800606", "ProductName":"EURONIX", "TotalQuantity ":"16", "TotalWeight":"25,0000", "UnitMeasureCode":"Kg" , "UsedQuantity":"0", "UsedWeight":"0,0000", "Weight":"25,00", "RemainingQuantity":"16", "RemainingWeight":"25,0000" }, { "CatId":"2", "InventoryDate":"24/11/2015 13:18:00", "CategoryName":"DETONATEURS", "ProductCode":"12640#143290051681", "ProductName":"PYRO ERIKA", "TotalQuantity":"100", "TotalWeight":"0,0000", "UnitMeasureCode":"Pcs", "UsedQuantity":"90", "UsedWeight":"0,0000", "Weight":"0,00", "RemainingQuantity":"80", "RemainingWeight":"0,0000 "}, { "CatId":"3", "InventoryDate":"24/11/2015 15:12:00", "CategoryName":"MECHES", "ProductCode":"50F207229#434299005", "ProductName":"MECHE LENTE", "TotalQuantity":" 8", "TotalWeight":"0,0000", "UnitMeasureCode":"Pcs", "UsedQuantity":"3", "UsedWeight":"0,0000", "Weight":"0,00", "RemainingQuantity":"2", "RemainingWeight":" 0,0000" }, { "CatId":"3", "InventoryDate":"24/11/2015 15:14:00", "CategoryName:":"MECHES", "ProductCode":"50F207229#434299006", "ProductName":"MECHE LENTE", "TotalQuantity":" 8", "TotalWeight":"0,0000", "UnitMeasureCode":"Pcs", "UsedQuantity":"0", "UsedWeight":"0,0000", "Weight":"0,00", "RemainingQuantity":"8", "RemainingWeight":" 0,0000"}, { "CatId":"3", "InventoryDate":"24/11/2015 15:15:00", "CategoryName":"MECHES", "ProductCode":"50F207229#434299007", "ProductName":"MECHE LENTE", "TotalQuantity":" 8", "TotalWeight":"0,0000", "UnitMeasureCode":"Pcs", "UsedQuantity":"2", "UsedWeight":"0,0000", "Weight":"0,00", "RemainingQuantity":"4", "RemainingWeight":" 0,0000" }, { "CatId":"2", "InventoryDate":"27/11/2015 19:40:00", "CategoryName":"DETONATEURS", "ProductCode":"UN0360#H34122", "ProductName":"LIGNE DE TIR NONEL", "TotalQuantity":" 120", "TotalWeight":"0,0000", "UnitMeasureCode":"Pcs", "UsedQuantity":"0", "UsedWeight":"0,0000", "Weight":"0,00", "RemainingQuantity":"120", "RemainingWeight":"0,0000" } ];

$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    data: localdata,
    colModel: [
        { label: 'CatId', name: 'CatId', key: true, width: 30 },
        { label: 'InventoryDate', name: 'InventoryDate', width: 70 },
        { label: 'ProductName', name: 'ProductName', width: 150 },
        { label: 'RemainingQuantity', name: 'RemainingQuantity', width: 150 },
        { name: 'TotalQuantity', index: 'TotalQuantity', width: 60, sortable: true, align: "center", search: false, sorttype: 'number', formatter: 'number', summaryType: 'sum' },
                { name: 'TotalWeight', index: 'TotalWeight', width: 80, sortable: true, align: "right", search: false, sorttype: 'number', formatter: 'number', summaryType: 'sum' },
                { name: 'UnitMeasureCode', index: 'UnitMeasureCode', width: 60, sortable: true, align: "right", search: false, formatter: 'string' },
                { name: 'UsedWeight', index: 'UsedWeight', width: 60, sortable: true, align: "right", search: false, sorttype: 'number', formatter: 'number', summaryType: 'sum' },
                { name: 'UsedQuantity', index: 'UsedQuantity', width: 60, sortable: true, align: "center", search: false, sorttype: 'number', formatter: 'number', summaryType: 'sum' }


    ],
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    viewrecords: true,
    rowList: [20,30,50],
    width: 780,
    height: 250,
    rowNum: 20,
    sortname: "ProductName",
    grouping: true,
    groupingView: {
        groupField: ["CatId"],
        groupColumnShow: [true],
        groupText: [
            "CatId: <b>{0}</b>"
        ],
        groupOrder: ["asc"],
        groupSummary: [true],
        groupSummaryPos: ["header"],
        groupCollapse: false
    }
});
```

The issue I have is that the summary row below each group is not well seen and identify visually.

How can I add a label like Total in front and then Hihlight that summary part with color ?

here is the link to the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zqLp4yrg/15/)

You can see that at then end of each group, the last row show a footer SUM of corresponding columns. I would like to set the background of those SUM cells and place the label Totals just in front.

regards

Comment: It would be helpful if you add jsfiddle demo which demonstrates your current state and to include the picture where you show where you want to have "Total" text. You use `groupSummaryPos: ["header"]` and ` groupText: ["CatId: <b>{0}</b>"]` and set the summary values in `TotalQuantity` column and later. Thus one can for example place the text "Total" in one from three columns: `InventoryDate`, `ProductName` or `RemainingQuantity`.

Comment: I have add the kink to the demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly your requirements, you can define

```js
summaryType: function () {
    return "Total:";
}
```

in `ProductName` column. The results will be on the modified demo: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/zqLp4yrg/20/

**UPDATE:** To change the background color of the summary row one have many ways. For example one can change in in the whole grouping footer row. One can use CSS setting like

```css
.jqfoot {
     background-color: DarkKhaki;
     background-image: none;
}
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/zqLp4yrg/24/.

There are exist `summaryTpl` property in `colModel` with the default value `{0}` which can be used to format summary cells. Thus one can specify

```js
summaryTpl: "<div class='mysum'>{0}</div>"
```

and to use

```css
.mysum {
    background-color: DarkKhaki;
    background-image: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

like on the https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/zqLp4yrg/25/. One should add more CSS rules to improve the look of the summary row, but all that will be pure CSS settings.

Comment: that is ik for the label Total but then how can I set the cell background color of sum results ?

Comment: @serge: It's the problem if one post multiple problems in one question. See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. You are the king :-)

Comment: @serge: By the way, I see that you are the member of stackoverflow since 4 years 3 months, but you used voting of questions or answers **only 3 times**. Voting in the main feature of stackoverflow, because *members* of stackoverflow decide whether some information is helpful or now. The voting will be used by searching engine end even Goodle use it during setting the order of displayed results. You have right to vote about 30 answers in a day (see [the post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)).

Comment: @serge: If you want to help other people **you should vote up every question or answer, which contains at least some helpful information**. You should do this not only on answers on your question, but in all questions of answers which you found on the stachoverflow. It's really important. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) for more information about voting.

Comment: @serge: I was sure that you just didn't known this. Only because of that I wrote you. Best wishes!

Comment: @Oleg Is there a way to sort the column based on group summary alone instead of inside fields? Please help. I am unable to post it as a question

Comment: @RustinCohle: You should post separate question, where you explain exactly what you do and what you need to implement. `sortname` parameter can be used in the form where multiple columns are specified, `sorttype` property of `colModel` can be defined as function, `sortfunc` can be additionally defined in `colModel` to implement more custom sorting. Thus there are many possibilities, but the features depend on `datatype` and other jqGrid options and depend on version and fork of jqGrid, which one uses. Thus new detailed question is required.

Comment: I am barred for some reason from posting additional question. Datatype is local. The grid is very similiar to the one available in demo: http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html in here with the grid name "Multi group one level sum". I want to sort the column Total by its summary. Please help.

Comment: @RustinCohle: I can't help you because *I don't understand what you need to implement and what problem you have*. You previous comments are not clear enough. The questions posted in comments will be *not indexed* and not found by other people. If you will don't post new question, then you want that I make *individual* consulting for you.

Comment: @Oleg I understand. I apologize. I have posted a separate question. Here is the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244380/how-to-sort-the-column-by-its-summary-value-alone-in-jqgrid-grouping) Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can set background color of group summary row using following `css`.

```
.ui-widget-content.jqfoot {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: none;
}
```

And you can set `Toatal` label like following in any column.

```
 summaryType: function () {
     return "Total:";
}
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zqLp4yrg/23/)