# How to sort the column by its summary value alone in jqgrid grouping

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have the code available here: https://jsfiddle.net/zqLp4yrg/41/

datatype is "local" not json.

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url: "/echo/json/", // use JSFiddle echo service
    postData: {
        json: JSON.stringify(serverResponse) // needed for JSFiddle echo service
    },
    mtype: "POST", // needed for JSFiddle echo service
    datatype: "json",
    colModel: [
        { label: 'CatId', name: 'CatId', key: true, width: 30 },
        { label: 'InventoryDate', name: 'InventoryDate', width: 70 },
        { label: 'ProductName', name: 'ProductName', width: 150 },
        { label: 'RemainingQuantity', name: 'RemainingQuantity', width: 150, summaryType: 'sum', sortable: true }

    ],
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    viewrecords: true,
    rowList: [20,30,50],
    width: 780,
    height: 250,
    rowNum: 20,
    sortname: "ProductName",
    grouping: true,
    groupingView: {
        groupField: ["CatId"],
        groupColumnShow: [true],
        groupText: [
            "CatId: <b>{0}</b>"
        ],
        groupOrder: ["asc"],
        groupSummary: [true],
        groupSummaryPos: ["header"],
        groupCollapse: true
    }
});
```

In here I want to sort the Remaining quantity based on its summary value in header. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your demo has many small problems:

- First of all you write about the usage of datatype is "local", but you use `datatype: "json"` in the demo. Moreover, you use no `loadonce: true` option and no `forceClientSorting: true` option. It means that **the server** is responsible for sorting the data. Moreover, if you use grouping, then the data returned from the server have to be sorted (on the server) by both `groupingView.groupField` (`CatId` in your case) and then by `sortname` (`RemainingQuantity` in your case). The data which you use as the source are **not sorted correctly**. One sees, for example, that jqGrid displays *two* `CatId: 2` and two `CatId: 3` groups.
- You can fix the problem by adding `loadonce: true` and `forceClientSorting: true` options, but you use old version of free jqGrid (4.11.1), which is not support `forceClientSorting: true`. You have to upgrade to the latest version (4.14.0) of free jqGrid to be able to sort and group the data returned from the server on the client *before* displaying.
- The source data, which contains integer data will be returned from the server as strings. Moreover, some data items contains spaces (`" 16"` instead of `"16"` or `16`). It changes the order of sorting the data.
- You should use `sorttype` (for example `sorttype: "integer"`) to sort the data in the column corresponds to the type of the data.
- To sort the date column correctly you should use both `sorttype: "date"` and the `formatter: "date"` with the `formatoptions` (in you case: `formatoptions: { srcformat: "d/m/Y H:i:s", newformat: "d/m/Y H:i:s" }`)
- If you want that the options `rowNum`, `rowList` and `viewrecords` work, then the grid have to have at least one pager. Thus you probably skip `pager: true` or `toppager: true` (or both) options.

The fixed demo is https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/zqLp4yrg/43/. I removed `groupingView.groupollapse: true` and `height: 250` only to make easy to examine the results. The settings are not important for your main problem.

Comment: Hi, I had to use that for the purpose of demo. I am using datatype: local. Updated the fiddle now. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/zqLp4yrg/44/). I want the column sorting based on the summary instead of the rows inside the group. By column sorting, I mean when you click on the column header records should sort based on grouping summary. Please help.

Comment: @MattMurdock: I repeat you that I don't understand what you mean under "I want the column sorting based on the summary instead of the rows inside the group". How "the column header records should sort based on grouping summary"? The column headers and the grouping headers are **only headers** and have no direct relation to **the data**. You can customize column headers and grouping headers to display any information on the place. jqGrid sorts **groups** and **rows**. The groups be sorted by `groupField: ["CatId"]` and by the data in the clicked column as the second sorting criteria.

Comment: to be more specific [link](https://jsfiddle.net/zqLp4yrg/45/) I have disabled collapsing. I want the column sorting to happen now on header click. Please help.

Comment: So is there any work around. I dont show the rows in grid. I show only the summary. Its like group summaries are my grid rows. So I want jqgrid to consider my summary as a row and sort based on summary value(total). Sorry for being confusing.

Comment: This is the result I am trying to achive(but with column sorting) [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqLp4yrg/46/)

Comment: @MattMurdock: Sorry, I'm busy now and have to do some thing for my main job. I will post you additional information later...

Comment: @MattMurdock: I think that there are still exist misunderstanding what jqGrid grouping do. jqGrid hold **the data**. It sort *the data* based on two sorting criteria and the displays *the data*. During displaying the data it inserts grouping headers *before the first row or the data* of the new group of the page. Even if the group is collapsed, *the sorted data* are still exist in the grid under the grouping header, but the rows have `display:none` style.

Comment: @MattMurdock: On click on the column `RemainingQuantity` header *the data* will be sorted by `CatId ASC, RemainingQuantity ASC` or `CatId ASC, RemainingQuantity DESC` and the results will be displayed. **If you need to change the order of groups (grouping headers)**, then you have to Implement **custom `sortype` or `sortfunc` in the column `CatId`**. *The sorting of `CatId` column is the only thing, which defines the order of the groups (or the grouping headers).*

Comment: Thanks. I understand jqgrid sorts only the rows not headers, To sort the grouping header, please tell me how should I proceed with sorttype on catId?

Comment: @MattMurdock: Do you mean that you can't find examples of writing `sorttype` or `sortfunc` or you have problems to access the summary information? `groups` property of `groupingView` contains all Information, which holds jqGrid about the groups. Every `groups` object contains `summary`, `value` and `keys` properties, which you could need. You can calculate summary **independent** from jqGrid and just include the value in the data. It allows to implement the mostly simple `sorttype` in `CatId` column.

Comment: Yes I am unable to access the summary values in sorttype function.It provides me only rowobject.

Comment: @MattMurdock: Yes of cause. I wrote you in my previous comment, that the most easy way will be to calculate the summary value, which you need to access, *independent* from jqGrid and to extend your data with the value (as an additional property). Then `rowObject` will have the property, which you need.

Comment: Its a vast amount of data and to summarise i need to group by two fields in json, its a tough task, seems thats the only way. Thanks.

Comment: @MattMurdock: If you many many data, then you hold the data in the database. SQL allows to calculate the summary very effective and very quickly. Thus you can really easy produce `CatId` to `Sum` map and include it in your server response.

Comment: thanks for your response. I have manipulated the data locally and added extra fields to pint in sorttype call. In sorttype custom call, how do I find if its order by desc or ascending? I get only rowobject and cellvalue.

Comment: @MattMurdock: `this`  is the DOM of grid. `var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");` is the reference on the options of the grid. Thus you can examine `p.sortorder`, `p.sortname` or any other options of jqGrid.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. I have one more issue. I have made the sorting work by pointing to extra column. However when two groups have same summary total(pointed value) the groups split. Are you able to guess the issue?

Comment: @MattMurdock: You are welcome! One should exactly analyse what you do now and what behavior you need to have. Sorting by `CatId` is required for correct **grouping**. You should take the fact in considerations in your implementation of `sorttype`.

Comment: Can I return two column values in sorttype?

Comment: @MattMurdock: I don't understand what you mean. Either you use `sortfunc` or `sorttype`. `sorttype` allows to replace *original values* from the column to another values, which can be used *instead of* the values in the column. `sortfunc` allows more flexibility. I recommend you to examine the code of [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/sortfunc.htm) (or https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/zkvwoj31/1/), which provides an example of the usage of `sortfunc`. See [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/192).

Comment: I completely understand. I have figured it out, manually adding some unique value for the grid to understand. Regarding my previous issue: $("#expenseGrid").jqGrid().setGridParam({
                sortname: 'Cost element name,', sortorder:
                'asc'
            }).trigger("reloadGrid"); this doesnt change my sortorder to desc.

Comment: @MattMurdock: Sorry, but I have to do my main job and I can't answer on comments in "chat" style. Switching from other problems to youth take always some time. I'm not sure that I understand correctly your last comment. One should be careful in `reloadGrid` and in changing `sortname`. It's very important *at what moment* or *inside of which callback* you changes `sortname`. The value of `sortname` should be the column name and thus don't contains spaces, commas etc. If you have new question, please post it separately and describe exactly what is your problem. The demo is helpful too.

Comment: I apologize. I will do that in the future. I have figured it out. Thank you for your inputs.